# ¿Como puedo auto llenar un input según el dato seleccionado en un dropdownlist?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, dropdownlist

[image: error mostrado en la consola][image: Error mostrado en la consola]Todo es desarrallado en asp.net core mvc con lenguaje C#.

El dropdownlist contiene como valores la identidad ingresada de ciertos clientes en una base de datos sql. Lo que deseo es mostrar en un input la fecha que pertenece al cliente según la identidad que se haya seleccionado en el dropdownlist.[image: Imagen de referencia]

Comment: Estás usando algún Store Procedure de esa base de datos?

Comment: Por los momentos no amigo, la base de datos que estoy utilizando por los momentos es una local la cual es creada directamente desde el asp.net

Comment: Soy niña amigo :(. Te recomiendo usar peticiones asincronas con ajax, jquery y js, para que al momento de seleccionar algún cliente, se haga una consulta a tu base de datos y te devuelva la fecha que pertenece al cliente, y ya con ese resultado anidas la fecha al input que deseas, todo ésto sin necesidad de recargar la pagina

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que cuando cargues los datos del dropDownList también cargues su valor de forma que crees un diccionario.

```
Dictionary<string, string> list = new Dictionary<string, string>();
list.Add("cliente_ID_1", "fecha_cliente_1");
list.Add("cliente_ID_2", "fecha_cliente_2");
list.Add("cliente_ID_3", "fecha_cliente_3");

ddl.DataSource = list;
ddl.DataTextField = "Value";
ddl.DataValueField = "Key";
ddl.DataBind();
```

De esta forma cuando selecciones un valor tendrás accesible automáticamente su clave.

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo usar funciones con peticiones asincronas, te dejo aquí una función que podría servirte

```
function obtenerfecha() {
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    async: false,
    url: 'obtenerFecha?idCliente='+ $("#txtCliente").val(),
    success: function (result) {

        $("#txtFecha").val(result);

        return resultado;
    }
});
};
```

En la url pondrías el nombre de tu método que te devuelve la fecha.
Esa función la utilizarías en el método OnChange() de tu dropdownList.

Espero que te sirva. Saludos.

Comment: El id del cliente logra ser identificado pero el código no termina de funcionar, indica un error de 404 (not found). Editaré el post para que se vea el error  que indica ya que no logro entenderlo @masha10

Comment: agregue los errores indicados en la consola con el código que proporcionaste. Parece que el id se logra identificar pero luego de eso pareciera que el código se detuviera.

Comment: Te esta diciendo el error que esa página no se encuentra o no logra acceder a esa ruta verifica que puedas entrar a esa ruta.

Comment: Hola, así es, no logra encontrar la ruta, valida que realmente puedas acceder a esa ruta, tal vez algo está mal escrito